# REGEXP_MATCH in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Although the BigQuery Standard SQL documentation mentions the function `REGEXP_MATCH`[1], it seems to be unavailable when running a query, with the web interface returning:

**Error**: Function not found: REGEXP_MATCH

What would be an alternative to using it?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_match

Comment: Thanks for the report, by the way. As Mikhail points out below, the preferred way of doing this is `REGEXP_CONTAINS`. I'm going to follow up with our doc writers to fix the mention of `REGEXP_MATCH`, which we don't intend to support since the semantics can be confusing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> what would be an alternative to using it?

You should use [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains)

Comment: function REGEXP_CONTAINS is undefined

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga - you should use it with BigQuery standardSQL - type #standardSQL in first line of your query or make sure to check in Options