# Big Query SQL regex for a field ending with a 7 digit number

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, where-clause

In my query, I am trying to filter the pagePath to only include pagePath values ending with a seven digit number.  How might I achieve this?

```
SELECT pagePath
FROM table
where pagePath (ends with a 7 digit number)
```

Comment: Try with `\d{7}$`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REGEXP\_MATCH in BigQuery Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575732/regexp-match-in-bigquery-standard-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
where regexp_contains(pagePath, '\d{7}$')
```

Regexp explanation:

```
\d     a digit (0 to 9)
{7}    quantifier (hence we want 7 occurences of a digit)
$      end of the string
```